# Using Java Enums and ArrayLists with JAX-WS in Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums, jax-ws, webmethod

I am currently building a web service using JAX-WS in eclipse (Juno, JavaEE).
I am limited to using JAX-WS and Java 1.6 (this is beyond my control to update)

The error I am getting when I try to generate a web service from my code is:

> The service class "webservice.WebService" does not comply to one or
> more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy
> or function correctly.
>
> The field or property "declaringClass" on the
> value type "java.lang.Enum" used via the service class
> "webservice.WebService" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is
> not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type
> may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete
> failure of the Web service may result.
>
> The field or property
> "referenceDataSet" on the value type "webservice.ReferenceDataSetList"
> used via the service class "webservice.WebService" has a data type,
> "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
> specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
> correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
> result.

The @WebMethod that generates this warning is:

```
@WebMethod
public RequestStatus setReferenceData(ReferenceDataSetList refData)
{
    // TODO
    RequestStatus status = new RequestStatus(Result.FAILURE);

    return status;
}
```

- RequestStatus is an object that contains and enum Result and and
  optional string message.
- ReferenceDataSetList contains an
  ArrayList and ReferenceDataSet has the same
  structure as RequestStatus (different enum type)

I have looked around and have been unable to find any solution to this warning.

I am not really sure where to look next...

**Edit**
I should add that I can run the service, but the error I get is when I try to generate to WSDL so that I can build clients

Comment: What is the JAX-WS runtime or what is the app server?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using JAX-WS and not JAX-RPC? The error message you are quoting refers to the JAX-RPC specification, which (at least as far as I can remember) did not have support for "native" Java enums, since it pre-dates Java 5.

Comment: @PaulVargas I am running the web service using 'Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8084/service", new WebService)'

Comment: @jarnbjo I thought it was JAX-WS but you make a good point, I am using eclipse to generate the webservice from my code, and cannot find anywhere that is specifying which it is using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what could be the problem. I am using the JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6 (this runtime is part of the JDK) and runs smoothly.

The enum:

```
public enum Result {
    FAILURE;
}
```

The response wrapper:

```
public class RequestStatus {

    private Result result;

    public RequestStatus() {
    }

    public RequestStatus(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

The request wrapper:

```
public lass ReferenceDataSetList {

    private List<String> list;

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

And the SEI class:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class TestService {

    @WebMethod
    public RequestStatus setReferenceData(ReferenceDataSetList refData) {
        return new RequestStatus(Result.FAILURE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8084/service", new TestService());
    }

}
```

The console output for this is:

```
28/02/2013 10:34:43 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class test.jaxws.SetReferenceData
28/02/2013 10:34:43 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class test.jaxws.SetReferenceDataResponse
```

I can see the WSDL in `http://localhost:8084/service?wsdl`. The schema for the list and the enum (fragment) is:

```
<xs:complexType name="setReferenceData">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:referenceDataSetList" 
            minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="referenceDataSetList">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="list" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="requestStatus">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="result" type="tns:result" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="result">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="FAILURE"></xs:enumeration>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, that has helped me understand what I have been trying to do more. Also I discovered that using eclipse to build the web service was not necessary as Endpoint.publish does that for you. I didn't realise that I didn't have to generate the WSDL within eclipse.